# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find in any atom class loader or parent class loader

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am trying to do some experiments with Instant Apps Documentation: [Android Instant Apps
Native Android apps, without the installation.](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html) I have followed steps which are covered on official docs. I have created emulator Nexus 5X to test instant apps features.

So, I have created two features in my project, which is much similar just kinda of demo to see how instant apps works. It was working well on one feature, now after when I created one more feature, now I have two features which in turns crashing my application.

```
05-24 12:07:12.259 12020-12028/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
05-24 12:07:15.952 12020-12020/com.williams.instantappdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.williams.instantappdemo, PID: 12020
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.williams.instantappdemo/com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: could not find com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity in any atom class loader or parent class loader
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: could not find com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity in any atom class loader or parent class loader
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.WhAppClassLoader.loadClass(WhAppClassLoader.java:100)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.WhAppClassLoader.loadClass(WhAppClassLoader.java:85)
            ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user/0/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/files/atom-cache/com.williams.instantappdemo/atom-download--base-1495607829279/base.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/files/native-lib/com.williams.instantappdemo, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.DexFirstClassLoader.doLoadClass(DexFirstClassLoader.java:50)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.WhAppClassLoader.loadClass(WhAppClassLoader.java:92)
            ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user/0/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/files/atom-cache/com.williams.instantappdemo/atom-download--feature-1495607829279/feature.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/files/native-lib/com.williams.instantappdemo, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.DexFirstClassLoader.doLoadClass(DexFirstClassLoader.java:50)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.loader.WhAppClassLoader.loadClass(WhAppClassLoader.java:92)
            ... 11 more
```

Here is **build.gradle** of feature module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':base')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Here is **build.gradle** for feature2:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':base')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is the **build.gradle** for base module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    feature project(':feature')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    feature project(":feature1")
}
```

Here is the **build.gradle** of app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nagarro.instantappdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':feature1')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: CNF exception means the JVM can't find the JAR containing that class.  It's most likely a packaging issue.  You're assuming you've done everything correctly, but the JVM tells you that's not true.  Look in the package and see if you can find that class.

Comment: In which module is MainActivity located? App module?

Comment: @MatPag `MainActivity` is located in both features module. Both features module has different package

Comment: Have you tried to use a different name? Maybe there are some conflicts during Manifest merging

Comment: I just tried with different name of activities in features, this didn't work for me

Comment: In the code example of the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html#structure_of_an_instant_app_with_multiple_features) seems that there is a dependency type called `application` in the last example code of the page. I don't see an application dependency in your app. Maybe you have something wrong in your dependencies configuration?. (Sorry if i can't be more specific, i never developed an instant app yet :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the actual activity package doesn't match what you have in your manifest file of the feature that contains MainActivity. It's a common error when refactoring activities into new packages and not using relative paths for activities in the manifest. Fully qualify the path to be absolutely sure

```
 <activity android:name="com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity"/>
```

Inspect the the apk file (build/outputs/apks) using `Apk Analyzer` to see if it has `com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity` in that exact package.

You can also use the [`Merged Manifest view`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) to inspect your final manifest (app module) to verify everything is in order.

Also, add application project(":app") to the base feature module so that it uses applicationId defined in your app module to package your app/instant app

**Update:**
Using the techniques described above, I investigated the merged manifests and found an issue. The build plugin ignored the numbers in the module name (`feature1`) so both features ended up having the same name. This caused a bunch of issues including the ActivityNotFound error.  Renaming the `feature1` module to `featureOne` resolved the issue.

Comment: I have added this "add application project(":app") to the base feature module so that it uses applicationId defined in your app module to package your app/instant app" and checked Merged Manifest View here it is https://pastebin.com/qrFXSuxg

Comment: I can see from the merged manifest data the Activity is packaged as  com.nagarro.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity and not com.williams.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity ADDED from [:base] C:\Users\williams\AndroidStudioProjects\InstantAppDemo\base\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-40
activity#com.nagarro.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity

Comment: Ah, some issue was there in my last paste bin. Check this https://pastebin.com/50jN9jXY

Comment: How are you calling the activity? Does this happen on launch of app or one activity starting another? It would really help if you paste all your merged manifest files from Instant App Zip -> Apk Analyzer -> for each feature apk -> AndroidManifest.xml https://pasteboard.co/12LcQE48D.png

Comment: It happens on launch of an app. here are my android manifest https://pastebin.com/1WdkXDNk

Comment: Did you include the features in your Instant App build.gradle just as you did for your regular app? https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#5 Please share the sample project over Drive and I'll take a look. I don't see anything wrong with the manifest.

Comment: Yes, it is already included in my app build.gradle . you can see project source code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/scns5knqqaegls3/InstantAppDemo.rar?dl=0

Comment: see the update to answer - Fixed project location https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Nu5U2Cz81qRTA4bzN3R01VaFU

Comment: Isn't this issue of build plugin, whatever name it is..it should build and run..right ?